# Find the root of f(x)=x^2 – 50 using a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, root-finding

I have this homework. But i don't know how to do it.

We did it with a `for` loop.

```
f=lambda x: (x**2)-27
fd=lambda x:x*2

a=50
for i in range(1,100):
    a = a - (f(a)/fd(a))
    print(i, ". root in step - ", a)
```

I think we are asked to turn this into a `while` loop and do it.

Comment: I think your instructor is looking for something like "while not converged: do Newton update". As a hint: convergence can for example be checked by figuring out if `f(a)` is already sufficiently small.

Comment: [Stack Overflow homework FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop should keep going until the delta between each step is smaller than the precision of a floating point number:

```
a = 50
while a > (a := a - f(a) / fd(a)):
    print(a)
```

This outputs:

```
25.27
13.169230312623665
7.609732014284865
5.578910083156939
5.2092825345429645
5.196168970075266
5.19615242273298
5.196152422706632
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/nAmHYw